# calling a lightbox div for user registration in index.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, lightbox

I have a problem that I have failed to solve.

Within my index.php, I am clicking on an anchor and calling a javascript function to display a lightbox that contains a form to capture user registration details. i.e:

```
<a href="javascript:loginLightBox();">register</a>
```

The div that contains the form:

```
<div class="userRegistration">
 <form name="userReg" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
 <label class="regLabel">Email address</label>
 <input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" class="regInput"/>
 <label class="regLabel">Password</label>
 <input type="text" name="userPassword" id="userPassword" class="regInput"/>

 <input type="hidden" name="userReg" value="1"/>  <!-- Note 1 -->
 <input type="submit" class="Button" value="Register" />
</form>
```

since this div is contained in index.php, you can see that the action for the form resubmits index.php, so I have php code that tests whether $_POST['userReg'] == 1 (see Note 1 comment in form above), i.e.

```
<?php
   if ($_POST['userReg'] == "1") {
       process the form, e.g check if userid already in database, etc etc.....

   }
?>
```

The problem I have is, if I refresh the page, since $_POST['userReg'] is in the user agent/web browser, and has been set to 1, the code will always try to reprocess the form.

I tried to unset($_POST['userReg']), but that will not work since the web browser resets it, thus once I submit the form, all subsequenct form refreshes will always get the lightbox redisplayed even when the user has registered, so my test for $_POST['userReg'] == 1 is useless, it will always be true.

The main difficulty is I would like to use just the main page(index.php) for user registration in a small corner of the page and avoid annoying the user with many pages to navigate to.

I have no AJAX knowledge in case that might be one way to solve this.

Others have suggested a concept known as POST-REDIRECT_GET, however this seems to redirect to a second page and I don't want to do this. Is there a way I can fix this problem.

Thanks for taking time to read my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A post variable is not in the User Agent, thats a string to identify the browser ;)

When you refresh the page after a submit, the browser (at least chrome) asks you if you want to resubmit the post data and then does the **exact** same request again including your post data.

If you really want to work arround this (and you can't check if the user is logged in or something like this) use a session variable:

```
<?php
session_start(); // call this at the top of your document

if ($_POST['userReg'] == "1" && !isset($_SESSION["reg"])) {
  $_SESSION["reg"] = true;
  // process the form, e.g check if userid already in database, etc etc.....
}
?>
```

A redirect may also work:

```
<?php
// this must be at the top of your document 

if ($_POST['userReg'] == "1") {
  // process the form, e.g check if userid already in database, etc etc.....
  header("Location: index.php?registration=".$status); 
  // use if($_GET["registration"] == "...") to give feedback
  // close db connection etc 
  die(); // and exit, the user is redirected

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Sebb. Use of SESSION variable is a quick win, although I'll explore a redirect later.